# Combining static data structures

Tags: c++

I am trying to come up with a good way to define data for a [seven-segment display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display).

Let's say that the display segments are named like this:

```
 -A-
F   B
 -G-
E   C
 -D-
```

So to display a `1` you need to turn on B,C - and for `2` you need A,B,G,E,D.

Furthermore, each line of the display is connected to an IO expander chip, and they are turned on by writing a `1` to the correct bit in the chip (over I2C, but that is not important).

Now I can structure my code like this:

```
enum Segments
{
    A = 0x02,
    B = 0x20,
    C = 0x10,
    D = 0x08,
    E = 0x04,
    F = 0x40,
    G = 0x01
};

enum class Digits
{
    D0 = A + B + C + D + E + F,
    D1 = B + C,
    D2 = A + B + G + E + D,
    D3 = A + B + C + D + G,
    ...
};
```

Which does give a correct and useful result (D0 = 0x7E, D1 = 0x30, etc.). HOWEVER! There is a wrinkle. I actually have a *dual* seven-segment display, and the two displays are not wired up identically internally (this is a hardware issue that I cannot change).

So now I am looking for a way to do something like this (pseudo-code):

```
enum Left_Segments
{
    A = 0x02,
    B = 0x20,
    C = 0x10,
    D = 0x08,
    E = 0x04,
    F = 0x40,
    G = 0x01
};

enum Right_Segments
{
    A = 0x02,
    B = 0x10,
    C = 0x40,
    D = 0x08,
    E = 0x20,
    F = 0x04,
    G = 0x01
};

template<class T>
enum class Digits
{
    D0 = T::A + T::B + T::C + T::D + T::E + T::F,
    D1 = T::B + T::C,
    D2 = T::A + T::B + T::G + T::E + T::D,
    D3 = T::A + T::B + T::C + T::D + T::G,
    ...
};

assert(Digits<Left_Segment>::D2 == 0x2F);
assert(Digits<Right_Segment>::D2 == 0x3B);
```

Or some other way of doing this, I am not attached to any specific notation. My goal is to define each digit once in a wiring-agnostic way, and then be able to plug in a specific wiring to produce the bit sequence to write to my chip. I would also appreciate if it was more type- and name-safe than old C-style enums.

Comment: "*My goal is to define each digit once in a wiring-agnostic way, and then be able to plug in a specific wiring to produce the bit sequence to write to my chip.*" So... why don't you do that? Why don't you just have a display-agnostic way to talk about the bits, then convert it for the specific display's arrangement when you want to interact with it?

Comment: As for the digits - you likely want to specify them as an array, so you can index them. For the segments, I'd just list the order of them and calculate values from that. Note that in modern C++ you have `consteval`, so it doesn't degrade runtime performance unnecessarily.

Comment: I would not use two different enums. I would use a single plain enum, whose values have nothing to do, whatsoever, with the hardware details, and have two separate classes that map the enum to their appropriate bitmasks. Or maybe two arrays.

Comment: Why not make the enums `enum class` since you access them with `T::` anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just missing a mapping from digits to the segments that should light up. Your current mapping is from digits to hardware addresses directly. Just don't do it all at once.

Actually for a nice visual code, I'd suggest to internally rename the segments like this:

```
 -S0-
S1  S2
 -S3-
S4  S5
 -S6-
```

In the following I will just use those indices as indices into an arary. I am not using an enum. If you prefer the enum you can replace the arrays with maps with the enum as key.

Now you can easily use arrays to define what segments should be activated for which digit:

```
std::map< int, std::array<int,7> mapping {
         { 1,  {     0,
                   0 , 1,
                     0,
                   0 , 1,
                     0 }   },
          { 2, {   ....
```

The segments to be activated for digit `x` are then elements of `mapping[x]` equal to `1`.

The hardware addresses you place elsewhere, eg in a

```
 std::array<int,7> addresses_display1, addresses_display2;
```

Then you can control either of the two displays via (not sure about details, I just produce the same sum you do):

```
 int get_sum( int digit,const std::map< int, std::array<int,7>& mapping, const std::array<int,7>& addresses) {
     int sum = 0;
     auto it = mapping.find(digit);
     if (it == mapping.end()) { 
             return sum; // error invalid digit
     }
     for (int i=0;i < 7; ++i) {
          sum += (*it)[i] * addresses[i];
     }
     return sum; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It is so simple, and I had a feeling it would be. But I kept staring myself blind and stupid on enums and template magic.